# Configuring French Macbook Pro (7.1) keyboard with Debian 6

Tags: debian, macbook, keyboard-layout, language

I have a Macbook Pro 7.1 with a French keyboard. I'm trying to install a Debian 6 guest OS using VirtualBox on it and I can't configure the keyboard as it is in OS X.

I tried `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` and selected the `mac-usb-fr` layout. Everything works well... besides the special characters (pound and arobase signs for example - first key under Esc).

When I select the Apple Macintosh Int'l layout using the keyboard settings in Gnome, I get an error dialog.

I also tried to edit /etc/default/console-setup and add these lines:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT="mac"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:switch,compose:lwin"
```

And these in /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Driver          "kbd"
Option          "CoreKeyboard"
Option          "XkbRules"      "xorg"
Option      "XkbVariant"    "mac"
Option          "XkbModel"      "pc105"
Option          "XkbLayout"     "fr"
Option          "XkbOptions"    "lv3:rwin_switch,apple:badmap"
```

Same error dialog when I reboot.

One surprising thing is that it works perfectly out of the box with Ubuntu, so I guess the problem has been solved. Maybe I am missing a specific package?

Comment: If you have a solution, **post it as an answer below** ("Answer your Question"), then you can mark it as accepted in two days. That way, everybody will see the answer right away and the question is marked as answered.

Comment: I confirm that the latest solution worked for me too, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps here worked for me: http://wiki.debian.org/MacBook#Keyboard.

I simply edited this file:

```
# /etc/default/keyboard
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT="mac"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:switch,compose:lwin"
```

And after a reboot, the mappings were good.